# Correct Syntax for this Selenium command

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am just not sure what will be the syntax for this 
This is a drop-down which changes its ID so I wish to choose the label above to navigate the click

Here is the HTML

```
<label class="form-title">Charging and Billing Alignment</label>
<select name="ratingAndBillingAlignment" class="reverse-toggle-select check-if-form-row-visible hide-child-if-not-visible loadable-drop-down-37 loadable-drop-down-select" id="ratingAndBillingAlignment" makeloadabledropdown="37" style="display: none;" fixed_position=".popup-content-inner">
<option value="TRUE" class="done-into-select-dd">Yes</option>
<option value="FALSE" selected="selected" class="done-into-select-dd">No</option>
</select><span num="37" class="loadable-drop-down loadable-drop-down-container loadable-drop-down-container-37" id="makeLoadableDropDown37" style="position: relative;" title="No" title2="No"><span class="dropdown-label initialized" style="width: 100%;"><span class="dropdown-html"><span class="value_box" style="display: none;">FALSE</span><span class="text">No</span></span></span><span style="display: none; position: absolute; width: 100%; left: 0px;" class="dropdown-list custom-drop-down-dropdown-list custom-drop-down-dropdown-list-37" stop="0" loading="0" data-counter="37"><div class="option-list" style="max-height: 250px;"><div class="dropdown-link  the-dd-counter-1 first-dd-link" c="1" title="Yes"><span class="dropdown-html"><span class="value_box" style="display: none;">TRUE</span><span class="text">Yes</span></span></div><div class="dropdown-link  the-dd-counter-2 last-dd-link selected" c="2" title="No"><span class="dropdown-html"><span class="value_box" style="display: none;">FALSE</span><span class="text">No</span></span></div></div></span></span>
```

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                "//span[@class='dropdown-label initialized']/following-sibling::label[contains(text(),'Charging and Billing Alignment')and(@xpath='1')]"))
                .click();
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `//label['Charging and Billing Alignment']` or `//span[@class='dropdown-label initialized']/preceding::label[1]` should be enough to select the label.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the xpath that you can use with name. As `name` does not update as it did in the case of id.

```
//select[@name='ratingAndBillingAlignment']
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot use this at it is hidden it gives me 
//select[@name='ratingAndBillingAlignment']
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Comment: I tried this says the same
 //span[@class='dropdown-label initialized']/preceding::label[1] it says org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

When I srch the DOM I find 2 ele with my sytx
```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                "//span[@class='dropdown-label initialized']/following-sibling::label[contains(text(),'Charging and Billing Alignment')]"))
                .click();
```
but It has 2 ele with same class i want 1st 
```
    <label class="form-title" xpath="1"></label>
    <label class="form-title" xpath="2"></label>
```

Comment: check if the elements are present in the iframe.

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: try this and see if it's pointing to the html tag in iframe. `//select[@name='ratingAndBillingAlignment']/ancestor::html`

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

Answer (score 0):

Locating `<select>` won't work in your case as its hidden. `style="display: none;"`

Try using below xpath to click on span looks alike dropdown

```
//label[contains(.,'Charging and Billing Alignment')]/following-sibling::span[contains(@class,'loadable-drop-down')]
```